# tuple object has no attribute "fit"

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, tuples

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

le_sex = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
le_sex.fit(['F', 'M'])
X[:,1] = le_sex.transform(X[:,1])

le_BP = preprocessing,LabelEncoder()
le_BP.fit([ 'LOW', 'NORMAL', 'HIGH'])
X[:,2] = le_BP.transform(X[:,2])

le_Chol = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
le_Chol.fit(['NORMAL', 'HIGH'])
X[:,3] = le_Chol.transform(X[:,3])

X[0:5]
```

The error I am receiving is "'tuple' object has no attribute fit in line 9"

I saw the other answers to the same question too they are saying to acess elements using index but I can't understand how to do the same in this question, Pleasse Help me understand it will be a huge help.

Thank you and have a great day!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure you add your whole error trace next time.

Anyway, I still found the error in your code. You have a comma instead of a period in the line

```
le_BP = preprocessing,LabelEncoder()
```

You need to replace the comma with a period as shown below

```
le_BP = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
```

Hope that fixed your problem.